# What is meant by "compile" the DOM?

Tags: angularjs

> Angular will then "compile" the DOM starting at the ngApp root element, processing any directives and bindings found along the way.

What exactly does compile mean in this instance?

Answer (score 1):

The ng-app directive is a starting point of AngularJS Application. It initializes the AngularJS framework automatically. AngularJS framework will first check for ng-app directive in a HTML document after the entire document is loaded and if ng-app is found, **it bootstraps itself** and **compiles the HTML template**

- Typically ng-app directives should be placed at the root of an HTML document e.g.  or  tag, so that it can control the entire DOM hierarchy. However, you can place it in any DOM element.
- The ng-app directive can also specify an application module name. This application module separates different parts of your application such as controllers, services, filters etc.

**bootstraping :-**
Angular initializes / bootstraps automatically upon DOMContentLoaded event or when the angular.js script is downloaded to the browser and the document.readyState is set to complete. At this point AngularJS looks for the ng-app directive. When the ng-app directive is found then Angular will:

**Compiling:-**
Compiler is an AngularJS service which traverses the DOM looking for attributes. The compilation process happens in two phases.

1. **Compile:** traverse the DOM and collect all of the directives. The result is a linking function.
2. **Link:** combine the directives with a scope and produce a live view. Any changes in the scope model are reflected in the view, and
       any user interactions with the view are reflected in the scope
       model. This makes the scope model the single source of truth.